# node redis visitor counter -throwing error

Tags: node.js, redis

I tried the code as per https://gist.github.com/hubgit/399898#file-node-redis-visitor-counter-js.
I saved the code in a js file named rediscounter.js and executing as "node rediscounter.js".Its showing output in console as "Server running at 127.0.0.1:6380"

But its throwing below error when I try hitting the url 127.0.0.1:6380 in browser,
crypto.js:240
  this._binding.update(data, encoding);
                ^
TypeError: Not a string or buffer
    at Hash.update (crypto.js:240:17)
    at Server. (/home/veera/Radha/rediscounter.js:7:40)
    at Server.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2109:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:122:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1967:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:528:27)

Should I host something in redis server?My redis server seems to be running fine.Please let me know what is the step I am missing out here.

Answer (score 0):

Referer header is not always present, so your call to hash.update fails here:

```
var urlhash = crypto.createHash("md5").update(request.headers.referer).digest("hex");
```

Check first if `request.headers.referer` exist.

Example:

```
zlatko@zlatko-desktop:~/tmp$ cat app.js 
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  res.write(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(req.headers)) + '\n');
  res.end();
}).listen(4040);

zlatko@zlatko-desktop:~/tmp$ curl http://localhost:4040
["user-agent","host","accept"]
zlatko@zlatko-desktop:~/tmp$ curl -H "Referer: google.com" http://localhost:4040 
["user-agent","host","accept","referer"]
zlatko@zlatko-desktop:~/tmp$
```

Comment: Np. An advice about your question: to make it more visible to people (and to make i tmore likely to get an answer), you should:
a) keep the code sample here, not on github (link is ok, but still copy over the relevant, minimal sample here)
b) do a little bit of formating.
It should make the question more easily readable.

Comment: I tried that way.and its not showing any error now.